# How to remove shipping address from onepage checkout?

Tags: shipping, address

I'm using Magento version 1.9.1.0.

I need to remove shipping address from onepage checkout. I did change the code as below

```
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
    return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
}
```

in `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`.

The problem is when click on continue button in billing page not going to shipping method page. Please let me know where else the code needs to be changed.

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before.
Please refer to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/how-to-remove-steps-from-the-magento-onepage-checkout

Comment: That code changes were about remove the shipping, shipping method, and payment steps. But I need to remove only shipping address. Also I'm not sure about how to change the code accordingly. Please suggest.