# How to remove Billing Address from Onepage checkout Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, billing-address

I am trying to remove the Billing address step from the Onepage checkout page in Magento, but facing issues. Can anybody please suggest how to remove the step from checkout page in magento.

I tried in the Core files, but it is showing errors.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove billing section from checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117319/remove-billing-section-from-checkout)

Comment: @sv3n this is older question then mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it by placing default values for the Billing address fields and added the below script in onepage.phtml

```
billing.save();
document.getElementById('opc-billing').style.display = 'none';
```

One after implementing this, i have removed the Billing address from Order Email,Order view page in admin.

Comment: not perfect solution..how to set billing id in billing.phmtl file??

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the Billing Adress from the checkout process, editing `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php`  and `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml` as suggested [here](http://www.opencart60s.com/magento/how-to-skip-billing-address-information-in-checkout-63-nbsp--828.html#thaoluan_2962) should work.

You might also be interested in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/how-to-remove-steps-from-the-magento-onepage-checkout?rq=1#7187).

Comment: Thanks for the answer SBALT. I checked this already but it is not working with the Latest Magento Version