# Skip custom shipping method step in checkout

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods

we are using 1.9.1.0.

we are using custom shipping method. I want to hide this in checkout....

I followed @Marius answer in below link & It worked fine for default shipping method. but not for custom shipping method that we are using.

[Remove Shipping steps in Onepage Checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout)

[image]

In custom shipping method we allowed only some zip codes.

```
<?php
class Exam_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Carrier_LocalDelivery extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
    /*  Use group alias */
    protected $_code = 'mpperproductshipping';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){        
    $postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();
    $restrictedCodes = array(

110001,
110002,


); //restricted values. they can come from anywhere
    if (!in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) { 
         return false;

    }   

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        /* Edited by vikas_mageworx */
        $postcode=$request->getDestPostcode();
        $countrycode=$request->getDestCountry();
        $items=$request->getAllItems();
        /* End Editing by vikas_mageworx */

        $postcode=str_replace('-', '', $postcode);
        $shippingdetail=array();

        /*  one start */
        $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode,'items'=>$items);
       /*  one end  */

         /* tt start - ship charges never work  
         $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode);
         tt end */


        foreach($items as $item) {
            $proid=$item->getProductId();
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                    $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                    if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                        $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $mpassignModel = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $partner = $mpassignModel->getSellerId();
            } else {
                $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$proid));
                foreach($collection as $temp) {
                    $partner=$temp->getUserid();
                }
            }

            $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid)->getWeight();
            $weight=$product*$item->getQty();
            if(count($shippingdetail)==0){
                array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
            }else{
                $shipinfoflag=true;
                $index=0;
                foreach($shippingdetail as $itemship){
                    if($itemship['seller_id']==$partner){
                        $itemship['items_weight']=$itemship['items_weight']+$weight;
                        $itemship['product_name']=$itemship['product_name'].",".$item->getName();
                        $itemship['item_id']=$itemship['item_id'].",".$item->getId();
                        $itemship['qty']=$itemship['qty']+$item->getQty();
                        $shippingdetail[$index]=$itemship;
                        $shipinfoflag=false;
                    }
                    $index++;
                }
                if($shipinfoflag==true){
                    array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
                }
            }
        }
        $shippingpricedetail=$this->getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail);

        if($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']!==""){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingCustomError($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']);
            return $result;
        }
        /*store shipping in session*/
        $shippingAll=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('shippinginfo');
        $shippingAll[$this->_code]=$shippingpricedetail['shippinginfo'];
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('shippinginfo',$shippingAll);

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));
        /* Use method name */
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/name'));
        $method->setCost($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']);
        $method->setPrice($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']); 
        $result->append($method);
        return $result; 
    }







public function getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail) {
        $shippinginfo=array();
        $handling=0;
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $customerAddress = $session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();


/* Edited by mage_boy */
$customerPostCode = $shippostaldetail['postalcode'];
$items = $shippostaldetail['items'];
 /* End Editing by mage_boy  */


 /* one  */

        foreach($shippingdetail as $shipdetail) {
            $seller = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($shipdetail['seller_id']);
            $sellerAddress = $seller->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            $distance = $this->getDistanse($sellerAddress->getPostcode(),$customerPostCode);
            // echo "distance ".$distance;die;
            $price = 0;
            $itemsarray=explode(',',$shipdetail['item_id']);
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $proid=$item->getProductId();
                $options=$item->getProductOptions();
                $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
                if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                    foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                        $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                        if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                            $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($proid))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                $mpshippingcharge = 0;
                $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
                $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
                $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
                if(in_array($item->getId(),$itemsarray)) {
                    if($mpassignproductId) {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getStateShippingCharge();
                        }
                    } else {
                         // echo "imte ".$item->getProductId();
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpLocalShippingCharge();
                            // echo "imte ".$item->getProductId();
                            // echo "ship ".$mpshippingcharge;
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpStateShippingCharge();
                        }   
                    }

                    /* tt */
                    // echo "test ".$mpshippingcharge;die;
                    if(!is_numeric($mpshippingcharge)){
                        $price=$price+floatval($this->getConfigData('defalt_ship_amount')* floatval($item->getQty()));
                    }else{
                        $price=$price+($mpshippingcharge * floatval($item->getQty()));
                    }
                    /* tt end */

                    /* one
                    if(floatval($mpshippingcharge)==0){
                        $price=$price+floatval($this->getConfigData('defalt_ship_amount'));
                    }else{
                        $price=$price+$mpshippingcharge;
                    }
                      one end */
                }
            }

            $handling = $handling+$price;
            $submethod = array(array('method'=>Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'),'cost'=>$price,'error'=>0));
            array_push($shippinginfo,array('seller_id'=>$shipdetail['seller_id'],'methodcode'=>$this->_code,'shipping_ammount'=>$price,'product_name'=>$shipdetail['product_name'],'submethod'=>$submethod,'item_ids'=>$shipdetail['item_id']));
        }
        $msg="";
        return array('handlingfee'=>$handling,'shippinginfo'=>$shippinginfo,'errormsg'=>$msg);
    }
```

[image]

what problem i am facing is ,

1)once we enter information under **Billing address**  as in above image with restricted zip code and it will move to "payment method " step. [ we removed shipping address step ] - This is wrong

[image]

2)again , if we move to "Billing address & click on "continue" ,it will show `Invalid shipping method` - This is fine.

[image]

**Means first time, it will allow for restricted zip code but it should not allow.**

as suggested in  the below answer, i used this [module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/reduced-checkout-free.html) .this also worked only for default shipping method.

Comment: what issue? Please describe briefly

Comment: @AmitBera i am getting error : "Invalid Shipping method" . but for default shipping methods its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can either get a module that does this like [this one](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/reduced-checkout-free.html)

Or write the code that hides the shipping method on your own, just search for "remove shipping on checkout" and get results like this:
[How to remove steps from the Magento Onepage checkout?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/how-to-remove-steps-from-the-magento-onepage-checkout/7187#7187)

Please note that I don't guarantee any of the modules, so you should try them on a test setup.

Comment: Thanks for information, but i am using only one custom shipping method, if i disabled that one, than we can not place an order. i want to hide only from frontend.

Comment: So, you want to hide it from the frontend whil keeping it in the backend so that you can create orders from the backend only? what about frontend? do you want to make the customers make orders without a shipping method?

Comment: i want customers can make order through frontend also. but i want to skip the shipping method step

Comment: Please see edited answer

Comment: i will check and inform you....

Comment: i used that extension that you suggested , but i am not getting required shipping method option in dropdown : http://prntscr.com/af05bp